# Lag variables for future prediction in Linear Regression in R

Tags: r, time-series, regression

I have a time series monthly data along with some derived variables (from date) and my dataframe can we created from the below code in **R language**.

```
Date = seq(as.Date("2018-06-01"), as.Date("2019-05-01"), by="months")
AMOUNT = c(1300,1023,3310,4120,4434,8700,355,453,590,880,1200,1811)
df = cbind.data.frame(Date,AMOUNT)
df$Seasonal = rep(1:12)
df$Month = lubridate::month(df$Date)
df$Lag1 = data.table::shift(df$AMOUNT,1L,fill = df$AMOUNT[1],type = "lag")
df$Lag2 = data.table::shift(df$Lag1,1L,fill = df$AMOUNT[1],type = "lag")
```

Top few rows from Sample Dataframe created: 
[image]

Now, I create a LinearRegression model like this:

```
model_LR = lm(AMOUNT ~ Seasonal+Month+Lag1+Lag2,data=df)
```

And I create data for forecasting the future AMOUNT:

```
Date = seq(as.Date("2019-06-01"), as.Date("2019-10-01"), by="months")
Seasonal = rep(1:5)
future_df = cbind.data.frame(Date,Seasonal)
future_df$Month = lubridate::month(future_df$Date)
```

How do I get Lag values for future_df so that I can use the "model_LR" object to do the future prediction? 
I can pick up values from 2019-05 and 2019-04 data for 2019-06 prediction as Lag values , but how do I include this forecasted value as the lag value while predicting for 2019-07 and months next?

Comment: You'll have to use a loop and go row by row based on the model you've created.

Comment: yes, but how do we do that in R?? probably we must have custom function of "predict", but is there an easy way?

Comment: Got it... Ignore my previous comment please :)